# struts interceptor running twice

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

I have just created some a struts interceptor.

```
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="alertableActionInterceptor" class="com.mycompany.web.interceptor.AlertableActionInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-stack name="eposWebAuditStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="alertableActionInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>            
    </interceptors> 

    <action name="healthCheck"
        class="com.mycompany.web.action.HealthCheckAction"
        method="input">
        <interceptor-ref name="eposWebAuditStack"/>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">page.healthCheck</result>
    </action>
```

This is how my interceptor looks like.

```
public class AlertableActionInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3149079243463745381L;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor#intercept(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation)
 */
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Running Inteceptor" + new Date());
    /* pre-processing */          
    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);

    /* call action */
    String result = invocation.invoke();          
    boolean doLogic = Boolean.valueOf(updateNotifications); 
    if (doLogic){
        System.out.println("Running Inteceptor with doLogicFlag");
    }       
    return result;
}
```

I have added some print statements to show that when I hit my healthCheck.action url, the interceptor seems to be executed twice even though I hit the Url once.

[image]

Can someone help me with why this might be happening?

I've added a screenshot here showing the http request in firebug. It looks here as if there is a root request and then a subsequent child request (doubled up). Am I reading this right? If so looks like somehow my http requests are bring doubled up.

[image]

Here is what the jsp looks like...

http://pastebin.com/Thv0rNLY (include 1)

http://pastebin.com/8PyueWkf (include 2)

http://pastebin.com/UweqAbp5 (include 3 -- content)

Comment: When you say twice, is it before and after the action is invoked ?

Comment: Not enough info. Which interceptor, when, why, what happens ? Post more info and more interceptor code please

Comment: More details will be required; what makes you think it's running twice--log statements? Are you sure there aren't two requests? There's no reason an interceptor would arbitrarily run twice for a single request.

Comment: Sorry guys. I didn't add enough info but I have added more now.

Comment: Are you using `<s:action>` tags in jsp? Or maybe doing some ajax request? Try to dispatch to empty jsp instead of tiles.

Comment: I am using s:submit but not s:action in my jsp. An action is not how the page is loaded though. But it is included in the page. I've added a trace of my http requests as this may help.

Comment: Better add your jsp-s.

Comment: 1) When posting comment, it's better using @dudesname to alert the dude that otherwise won't know you've done something; 2) Avoid using scriptlets 3) Try removing `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; url=/xxxx/xxxx.action">` 4) Try removing your javascript function setting location.href 5) lol @ `ie-sucks.css` :P